# Why does Refresh work without MFA?

Tags: yodlee

I have been testing jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1 on multiple banks (B of A, Wells, Chase, etc.) and while those sites use security questions in normal browsers I am wondering why the refreshes are working without me submitting MFA info.  The refreshes are completing and I am able to view transactions.  Can someone please explain this to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which Yodlee gets the data from banks -

- Data Feeds - From banks with which Yodlee has partnerships (Mostly the top US banks)
- Scrapping - From banks where data feed is not an option, Yodlee does screen scrapping.

In case where yodlee has partnerships with banks and gets data feed , you will not have to go through the MFA flow, which is why you may not be asked MFA information while linking those accounts.

Comment: Can you please give me the name of a couple sample banks that Yodlee has to scrape data from?  I would like to test MFA flow with them.